# How do I return an array from Rxjs subscribe method?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have this code:

```
Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6])
.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

How can I return an array from subscribe instead of the subscribe iterating through the array elements from the .from() method?

I want the x argument to be an array and to console.log() this array.

Comment: `Observable.of([...])`? `.from` emits each thing in the iterable as a separate element of the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReactiveX has the "to" operator, which can be used with RxJS as `toArray`:

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/to.html

```
Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

Comment: Tnx, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Or, pass it like this:

```
Rx.Observable.from([[1,2,3,4,5,6]]);
```

an array whose first element is an array.